# I use torch update function, but my matrix don't update

Tags: pytorch, torch, torchvision

in this code n1.shape and n2.shae are (1,64,112,112)
n1 is target matrix and n2 is noise matrix

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

sub_param = nn.Parameter(n2)
optimizer = optim.SGD([sub_param], lr=0.1)
loss_criterion = nn.MSELoss()

for epoch in range(5):
    optimizer.zero_grad() 
    
    loss = loss_criterion(n1,sub_param)
    
    loss.requires_grad_(True)

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()  

    #print(sub_param.data)
```

the output is

```
tensor(0.4234, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>)
tensor(0.4234, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>)
tensor(0.4234, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>)
tensor(0.4234, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>)
tensor(0.4234, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward0>)
```

why isn't n2(sub_param) updated..?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you just need to leave out the line

```
loss.requires_grad_(True)
```

If you read the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.requires_grad_.html) of requires_grad_, you see that it causes the autograd system, to start recording operations on your tensor. You would use this in one tensors you want to update later, but you loss should be a 'leaf' node in the [autograd system](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html) - it provides a calculational starting point for back propagation. You don't need this, I think simply removing that line should solve the issue.

Also, notice that what is being printed, is the gradient of the loss itself, and not your embedding.

Comment: i test n1,n2's shapes (1,10) in same code then loss has decreased. i think the shape (1,64,128,128) and mse loss don't seem to fit

Comment: I did some more testing, and maybe the problem is that your tensor is just too big. Maybe making a step with learning rate 0.1 just yields so little change in each coordinate that it vanishes. You could increase the learning rate.

Comment: i use adam optimizer instead of sgd, so loss is decreased and my matrix is updated!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, since ADAM changes it's learning rate during iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is because your gradients are very small. Don't forget that the MSE function you use is actually:

`torch.mean((n1 - n2)**2) = torch.sum((n1 - n2)**2) / (64 *112 * 112)`

So the gradients wrt n1 are like:

`grads = (1/401408) (n1 - n2)`

For instance try to use the sum instead of mean in your loss function:

```py
def loss_criterion(x: torch.Tensor, y: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    """MSE reduced by sum."""
    return torch.sum((x - y) ** 2)
```

Changing the LR with Adam can also work but it is far less optimized. It is like your starting lr is 1e-7.

Note: `loss_criterion.requires_grad_(True)` has absolutely no impact since `loss_criterion` is not a parameter to update.